# Can't show image in my ReactJs application

Tags: reactjs

```
return (
    <Card>
      <CardHeader
      title="Full Name"
      subtitle="@username"
      avatar="./../assets/img/image.gif" />
      <CardText expandable>
        <div>
          <p>{message}</p>
        </div>
        <div>
          {tagElements}
        </div>
      </CardText>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

Folder structure:

```
- app
-- assets
--- img
---- image.gif
-- src
```

Do I need to import something on every js file where I would like to show images? Why can't I just point to the folder where it's located and just show it? What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

In the CardHeader component you will need to import the Image component from react native and supply the uri prop to that component to render. Here is the [documentation for image](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html)

`import {Image} from 'react-naitve'`

One gotcha with react native is that you need to provide explicit width and height to the image in order for it to render. Otherwise it appears as 0x0.

So something like this within your CardHeader would work:

`<Image
    style={{width: 50, height: 50}}
    source={{uri: props.avatar}} />`

Comment: Yeah it's react.js, not react-native.

Comment: ahh my bad. I should have read the title thoroughly before I answered. Can we see what the CardHeader component looks like?

Answer (score 0):

You have to import your image and then use it. It is enough to add the image path in your js file header. Example:

```
import myimage from 'XXX/images/x.png';
```

Then you have to show it like that:

```
 <div className="myimage">
    <img src={myimage}  />
 </div>
```

Let me know if it is works for you.